# Missing daily data for one month

Tags: time-series, missing-data

I have a two years of daily data. The data for one month is missing as it was not recorded due to some problems at the company. How should I treat the data with no values for a month.

Comment: I think it really depends on your goals.  Are you trying to fit a certain model, or generate plots, or make predictions about the future?

Answer (score 1):

The missing observation would be best handled by identifying the normal patterns in the data.  Once you have modeled the time series, this missing observation will be flagged as an outlier.  The fitted value in the model will tell you what the value should have been.

This is how we do it.....

I would create 6 day of the week fixed effects variables and 51 week of the year fixed effect variables. I would create regression variables for each public holiday. I would use the cross-correlation function to identify lead/lag relationships around those holidays. I would search for outliers, level shifts, local time trends and seasonal pulses. I would also consider adding in any other macro causals (ie population, unemployment) or know historical events.

I would search for monday after holiday landing on friday impacts (ie using a regressor). I would search for friday before after holiday landing on monday impacts (ie using a regressor).

I would search for "fixed days of the month" impacts due to paycheck distribution.

If you are trying to forecast energy consumption then also add in weather variables.

All of this is done to get a good read on the "model" and hence a quality forecast.

I'd be happy to discuss with you "off line" how to do this....automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to use day-of-the=wekk averages for the 4 months surrounding the "missing month" to obtain initial estimates of the daily vales for the "missing month". I would then entertain a model that used day-of=the-week and week-of-the-year indicators. I would then detect anomalies which would then allow me to replace the "current values" for the "missing month" and re-iterate until some convergence was reached.